# Does a template function with different definitions cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, one-definition-rule

**0.cc**

```
template <class T>
T get(){
 return 5;
}

int get(){
 return 6;
}

int main(){
 return get<int>();
}
```

**1.cc**

```
template <class T>
T get(){
 return 7;
}
template int get<int>(); // This forces code generation.
```

Compiling with `g++ -Wall 0.cc 1.cc` causes no link errors, returned output is `5`.

**Questions**

1- Do templates have external linkage by default even if `extern` isn't used?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

> names of all templates not listed above (that is, not function templates declared static).

2- Does the linker treat multiple templates like `inline` functions? i.e it chooses 1 out of many definitions and having different definitions causes UB?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356946

3- Why doesn't `int get(){}` cause a link error? do template functions and regular functions have different symbols?

Comment: ODR is broken... program is ill-formed, no diagnostics required.

Comment: That's three distinct question. And they aren't terribly related.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica they kind of get related when i'm trying to understand how and why this compiles.

Comment: That does not make them related insofar as the one question per question rule https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a template function with different definitions cause undefined behaviour?

Yes.

> 1- Do templates have external linkage by default even if extern isn't used?

Yes, template functions have external linkage unless declared in anonymous namespace or if declared `static` or if attached to a module and is not exported.

> 2- Does the linker treat multiple templates like inline functions?

Yes. Implicit instantiations of function templates are treated the same as inline functions in this regard.

> and having different definitions causes UB

Yes. Technically, the program is ill-formed, but the distinction between those doesn't really matter at runtime.

> 3- Why doesn't int get(){} cause a link error?

Overloading function template with a function is well-formed.

Comment: *"Function templates are implicitly inline."* Nah. Multiple definitions of them are allowed, but not because of inline-ness. You can manually mark them `inline` as a hint to the optimizer.

Comment: For question 3, is it legal? This answer says it might be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865452

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I adjusted wording.

Comment: In the above link `f` is a regular function and also a template. The answer says it's legal to do so. That's also my question #3.

Comment: @Dan I see. I thought you meant because of the two different template definitions. I've edited the answer.

Comment: ill formed code is free to produce code that does UB even if the ill formed code would never be run.

Answer (score -1):

**Does a template function with different definitions cause undefined behaviour?**

Answerr: Well, Yes, templates do behave undefined if you define them in multiple ways.
There should be only one definition

```
BUT
You can use template in some other scope in with different definition
```

**Do templates have external linkage by default even if external isn't used?**
Answer:

```
Yes,
Templates will cause external linkage in normal circum stances but some exceptions are
Defining them in some outer namespace or using them as an exports.module
```

**Does the linker treat multiple templates like inline functions? i.e it chooses 1 out of many definitions and having different definitions**
Answer:
Obviously, Templates are treated as an inline function